# Registros duplicados na tabela do banco

Tags: php, codeigniter, loop, sql-insert

Tenho a seguinte **model**:

```
function validarQuestionario()
{

    if(is_array($this->input->post('resposta[]')) || is_object($this->input->post('resposta[]')))
    {
        foreach ($this->input->post('resposta[]') as $single_resp) 
        {

            foreach ($this->input->post('idMarcacao[]') as $single_id)
            {
                $data['respostaAluno'] = $single_resp;
                $data['idMarcacao'] = $single_id;
                $this->db->insert('tbdquestionario', $data);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Ao invés de ser registrado 10 linhas que seria o valor correto, **está sendo registrado 100 linhas no banco.**

Comment: se o resposta[] e o idMarcacao[] forem 10 cada um 10 x 10 = 100 correto?

Comment: Exato, mas como eu poderia  recuperar os dados para fazer o Insert, sem o foreach?

Comment: Só para confirmar, está utilizando o CodeIgniter? Pela sintaxe parece ser ele, por isso inseri a tag, mas se não for posso removê-la.

Comment: Você vai fazer o `for` normal `for($i = 0; $i < count(resposta[]);$i++) { resposta[$i] ... // assim por diante }`

Comment: @Woss, é Codeigniter sim!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não utilizo o CodeIgniter para ter autoridade completa sobre o que falarei, mas partirei da análise básica do PHP:

Considerando que `$this->input->post('resposta[]')` retorne um *array* com os valores no campo `resposta[]`, que `$this->input->post('idMarcacao[]')` também retorne um *array* com os valores no campo `idMarcacao[]` e que ambos os *arrays* possuem o mesmo tamanho (não me preocuparei em validar isso), você pode fazer:

```php
$respostas = $this->input->post('resposta[]');
$ids = $this->input->post('idMarcacao[]');

$data = array_map(function ($resposta, $id) {
  return compact('resposta', 'id');
}, $respostas, $ids);

$this->db->insert_batch('tbdquestionario', $data);
```

E só. Supondo que o *array* de respostas seja algo como `['a', 'c']` e o *array* de ids `[1, 2]`, a função `array_map` irá gerar um *array* no formato:

```php
$data = array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'resposta' => 'a',
    'id' => 1,
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'resposta' => 'c',
    'id' => 2,
  ),
);
```

E, conforme a [documentação](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert_batch#inserting-data), o método `insert_batch` pode receber um *array* de *arrays* para inserí-los de uma vez (não é viável fazer um por um), a menos que queira gerenciar as transações independentemente.

**Tarefa de casa:** por que uma função que faz inserções no banco de dados se chama `validarQuestionario`?

Comment: Opa, o nome dessa função realmente não deveria ser esse, alterei. Valeu por avisar.

Comment: Alterei o código para o que você sugeriu, porém retornou este erro (editei colocando a foto do erro).

Comment: @Ckpy Porque precisa ser array associativos indicando o nome da coluna de cada valor... Acho que consegue resolver isso a partir do que eu passei

Comment: Deu certo, amigo. Muito obrigado, de verdade